# add to a binary search tree, return a boolean

Tags: java

I've managed to add the nodes correctly using recursion.

I've run into a problem while trying to keep a count, my recursion method returns false (multiple times) before adding a node. Seems like it would work without returning false at the end but java is not liking that.

How do I get around this?

here's the (psuedo-ish) code:

from set class:

```
if(root.add(value))
    count++
    return true
return false
```

from node class:

```
    public boolean add(item value) {
    if(this == value) //check if it already exists
        return false;
    } else {
        if(this.left < value)
            if(this.left != null)
                this.left.add(value)
            else
                this.left = new Node(value)
                return true
        if(this.right > value)
            if(this.right != null)
                this.right.add(value)
            else
                this.right = new Node(value)
                return true
    }
    return false
    }
```

Comment: The pseudo-ish code has some basic syntax issues which I am assuming is corrected in the code. What I don't understand is why you return false at the end. It means it is bound to return multiple false when the function call stack is pulled.

Comment: it requires a return false at the end because your method has a return type. and it is saying that it is possible to get to teh end of your method without having hit a return.

Comment: @ND_27 I believe that is what his question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return whatever the recursive call returns?

```
public boolean add(item value) {
if(this == value) {
    return false
} else if(this.left < value) {
    if(this.left != null) {
        return this.left.add(value)
    } else {
        this.left = new Node(value)
        return true
    }
} else { //if(this.right > value)
    if(this.right != null) {
        return this.right.add(value)
    } else {
        this.right = new Node(value)
        return true
    }
}
}
```

Btw, even though this is pseudo-code; the if's are (afaict) a bit incorrect? You're checking if the left node is less than value to add and if so you're adding the value to the left node... If I'm not mistaken you usually add smaller values left and higher values right so you might want to swap that. (I'm assuming you've got this correct in code though.)

Answer (score 0):

At first, are you sure, the problem is not because you have wrong formating? This is right formating due to your code. As you can see, the `if (this.right > value)` is never reached...

```
public boolean add(item value) {
    if (this == value) {  //check if it already exists
        return false;
    } else {
        if (this.left < value) {
            if (this.left != null) {
                this.left.add(value);

            } else {
                this.left = new Node(value);
            }
        }
        return true;
        if (this.right > value) {
            if (this.right != null) {
                this.right.add(value);

            } else {
                this.right = new Node(value);
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```